# See which package has another installed package as a dependency

Tags: apt

I have a package installed automatically (I am sure of it because I run `apt list --installed | grep <mypackagename>`) on my Debian 10 GNU+Linux system and I'd like to know which other (manually) installed package required its installation, but I do not know how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aptitude` can tell you:

```
aptitude why <yourpackagename>
```

will show the strongest relationship between a manually-installed package and `<yourpackagename>`, and

```
aptitude -v why <yourpackagename>
```

will show you all such relationships.